# Enviar formulario desde una ventana modal

Tags: java, jsp

Trabajo en una app web con jsp. Estoy realizando un formulario en una ventana modal con bootstrap, este es el código del body de la ventana modal.

```
<%@page import="DataBase.Querys"%>
<%@page import="Bean.Categoria"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>

<!--
- Ask Simon 
- Missael Armenta Peralta
- 
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Ask Simon - Categories</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/escudo.png" >

    <link href="../home/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../home/css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <base target="_blank" />
</head>


<body id="page-top" class="index">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">


        <div class="container">


            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>


                <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
                    <a href="http://t-systems.telekom.de/cms/tsi-mx/es/news/templateId=renderInternalPage/id=1538902.html">
                        <img src="../home/img/t-systems.png">
                    </a>
                </div><!--col-lg-12 text-left-->


                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href ng-click="cominghome()">Welcome to Ask Simon</a>
                </div><!--col-lg-12 text-center-->


            </div><!--navbar-header page-scroll-->


            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href ng-click="cominghome()"></a>
                    </li>



                    <li>

                     <a class="page-scroll" href ng-click="users()">Users</a>


                    </li>

                     <li>

                     <a class="page-scroll" href ng-click="helpp()">HELP</a>


                    </li>


                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href ng-click="goback()" >Logout</a>
                    </li>


                </ul>
            </div><!--id= "bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"-->

        </div><!-- container -->

    </nav><!--navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top-->


    <!-- Categories Grid Section -->
    <section id="portfolio" class="bg-light-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Categories</h2>
                    </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">

               <!--CICLO PARA COLOCAR LAS AREAS DE FORMA DINAMICA-->
               <%
                Querys DB=new Querys(); //OBJETO PARA CONSULTA LA BASE DE DATOS
                ArrayList<Categoria> categories=DB.MostrarCategorias();//OBTENEMOS LA LISTA DE CATEGORIAS


                for(int i=0;i<categories.size();i++) //CICLO PARA RECORRER TODAS LAS AREAS
                {
                    //Div General
                    out.println("<div class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item'>");

                        //Div Imagen
                        out.println("<a href=''  class='portfolio-link' data-toggle='modal'>");
                            out.println("<div class='portfolio-hover'>");
                                out.println("<div class='portfolio-hover-content'>");
                                    out.println("<i class='fa fa-plus fa-3x'></i>");
                                out.println("</div>");
                            out.println("</div>");
                            String rutaImagen="../img/"+categories.get(i).getIdCategoria()+"."+categories.get(i).getExtencion(); //ALMACENA EN UN STRING LA RUTA DE LA IMAGEN
                            out.println("<img src="+rutaImagen+" class='img-responsive' alt=''>");  //MUESTRA LA IMAGEN                       
                        out.println("</a>");//Termina Div Imagen

                        //Div Nombre
                        out.println("<div class='portfolio-caption'>");
                            out.println("<h4>"+categories.get(i).getNombre()+"</h4>"); //MUESTRA EL NOMBRE
                        out.println("</div>"); //Termina Div Nombre

                    out.println("</div>");//Termina Div general
                }


                %><!--TERMINA CICLO PARA COLOCAR LAS AREAS DE FORMA DINAMICA-->





                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item"><!-- Add Categories--> 
                    <!--ESTA SECCION NO CAMBIA POR TANTO QUEDA ESTATICA -->
                    <a  class="portfolio-link" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">

                        <div class="portfolio-hover">

                            <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <img src="imgareas/arey.png" class="img-responsive" alt=""> 
                    </a>

                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Add Categorie</h4>                 
                    </div>

                </div><!-- End Add categorie-->



            </div><!-- row -->

        </div><!--container-->

    </section><!--portfolio-->


<!-- Add Categorie -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add a new Categorie</h5>
            </div><!--modal-header-->

            <div class="modal-body">

                Please, complete the requested information

                <form name="AddCat"  action="./insert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>

                    <label>Name of categorie</label><br/>
                    <input type=text size=60 name="nombreCat" required class="form-control"><br><br>

                    <label>Image of categorie</label><br/>
                    <label></label>
                    <input type=file size=60 name="file2" required><br><br>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save changes"></input>

                </form><br><!-- AddCategorie -->

            </div><!--modal-body-->


        </div><!--modal-content-->

    </div><!--modal-dialog-->

</div><!--modal fade-->

<!-- End Add Categorie form-->





   <!-- Footer -->
    <!-- Estas lineas enlazan el footer para reutilizar codigo -->
    <script> var modulo= angular.module('includes',[])</script>         
    <footer ng-include src=" '../enlaces/footer.html' "></footer>
    <!-- End Footer -->


    <!--Enlaces para la ventana modal-->
    <script src="../home/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../home/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../home/js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="../home/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
    <script src="../home/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="../home/js/contact_me.js"></script>

</body>
```

El problema es que no envía el formulario. Le doy clic al botón pero no me envía a ninguna parte. El archivo insert es un servlet y ya lo he declarado en el web.xml  ¿Alguna idea de por que sucede esto?

Configuración del archivo web.xml

```
<servlet-config>
    <servlet-name>insert</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Servlets.insert</servlet-class>
</servlet-config>
```

Archivo servlet en blanco solo lo he creado con netbeans aun no empleo nada de código pero debería abrir el servlet como tal y mostrar una pagina en blanco pero se queda en la ventana modal

```
/**
 *
 * @author Missael
 */
@WebServlet(name = "insert", urlPatterns = {"/insert"})
public class insert extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet insert</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet insert at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
```

Comment: ¿Tu servlet soporta el envío de datos como multipart/form-data?

Comment: no, bueno no he leído nada acerca de eso es un servlet  común, podrías  explicar un poco a que te refieres ?

Comment: Sería mejor si colocas el código de tu servlet y la configuración que utilizas actualmente para manejar la carga de archivos. Sobre eso, puede que yo u otro usuario explique en más detalle lo que sucede y cómo puedes corregirlo (si es que mi sospecha es acertada).

Comment: Listo lo acabo de agregar, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No creo que sea un problema del servlet es mas bien un tema de HTML. corrobora que no tengas un <form> dentro de otro.

Comment: @JuanM.Hidalgo lo es. Revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: @JuanM.Hidalgo edite la pregunta para mostrar todo el codigo de la ventana modal, yo no encuentro errores de html, espero que tu si jeje gracias

Comment: @MissaelArmenta Habria que ver el html fuera del modal que no haya ningún <form > encerrando el modal.
Probaste usar las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador para ver si la petición esta saliendo?

Comment: Por favor presiona la tecla F12 en tu navegador (Firefox/Chrome) y ve a la pestaña Redes/Network. Revisa que cuando seleccionas el botón se dispara alguna petición al sevidor. Asimismo, luego revisa en la consola JavaScript si aparece algún mensaje de error. Brinda esos detalles para seguir ayudándote.

Comment: Veo que estas usando angular, tal vez tenga algo que ver?

Comment: pues espero que no jeje  solo lo uso para enlazar  otras paginas y reutilizar código ya que no se me permite usar php  y con iframe no puedo  heredar estilos y el atributo import en html5 limita los equipos que podrían abrir el sitio

Comment: @MissaelArmenta ¿Seguiste las recomendaciones que te hice? ¿Pudiste ver si al presionar el botón se envía una petición al servidor o si aparece algún error en la consola que impida la ejecución del envío del formulario?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo visto utilizas Servlets 3.0 puesto que configuras el servlet con anotaciones. Si utilizas las anotaciones, no necesitas utilizar la configuración en web.xml, por lo que te recomiendo que elimines esa configuración del xml.

Tu servlet está recibiendo una petición de tipo multipart/form-data, la cual se utiliza para recibir datos del formulario en partes. El servlet necesita conocer que va a atender peticiones de este tipo, por lo cual necesitas agregar la anotación [`@MultipartConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html):

```
@WebServlet(name = "insert", urlPatterns = {"/insert"})
@MultipartConfig
public class insert extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        //procesar el archivo aquí...
    }
}
```

Con dicha anotación, el servlet podrá manejar las peticiones de partes (el archivo). Puedes utilizar el siguiente código dentro del método `doPost`:

```
String nombreCat = request.getParameter("nombreCat"); //para <input type="text" name="nombreCat" />
Part archivo = request.getPart("file2"); //para <input type="file" name"file2" />
InputStream streamArchivo = archivo.getInputStream();
//lee el contenido del archivo mediante el InputStream
//lo puedes guardar en disco, guardar en base de datos, utilizar para otro proceso, etc
```

Comment: Ya lo agregue pero sigue sin avanzar, la ventana modal no redirecciona ni se cierra ni nada  jeje

Comment: @MissaelArmenta provee todo el código de tu página para ver qué sucede.

Comment: acabo de agregar todo el código de la pagina

Comment: un pregunta con el código que pusiste  arriba podria acceder por ejemplo a la ruta del archivo  y nombre para copiarlo a una carpeta dentro de mi proyecto ? y como hago esto? gracias